# Factory method 'transactionAdvisor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: jpa, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-cloud-config

I have a standard spring boot application using JPA and Spring config. The problem is when I am trying to bootRun the application it fails to initialize "transactionAdvisor" and throws `NullPointerException`. As a result the app is not able to create any of my bean and complains about:

> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException.

For all my entities it says:

> Not a managed type.

Any help on this will be highly appreciated since banging my head on this for a while now.

Can provide further details if required.

Exception:

> 2016-12-28 08:56:43,908 ERROR [main] SpringApplication: Error handling
>   failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'delegatingApplicationListener' defined in
>   class path resource
>   [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]:
>   BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
>   defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/transaction/annotation/ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor]:
>   Factory method 'transactionAdvisor' threw exception; nested exception
>   is java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:478)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.retrieveApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:228)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.getApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:185)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:121)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.publishEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:111)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.finished(EventPublishingRunListener.java:98)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.callFinishedListener(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:79)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.finished(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:72)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:833)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:318)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)
>     at com.XXXX.XXXXX.audit.Application.main(Application.java:27) Caused
>   by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
>   defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/transaction/annotation/ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor]:
>   Factory method 'transactionAdvisor' threw exception; nested exception
>   is java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:92)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:85)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:103)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:248)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:988)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:959)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
>     ... 17 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor]:
>   Factory method 'transactionAdvisor' threw exception; nested exception
>   is java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
>     ... 33 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: null  at
>   org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.transactionAdvisor(ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.java:46)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$54296c56.CGLIB$transactionAdvisor$0()
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$54296c56$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ba4a4fd2.invoke()
>     at
>   org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$54296c56.transactionAdvisor()
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
>     ... 34 common frames omitted :bootRun FAILED